# Do the irrationals form a group?

Tags: group-theory

It's true that the irrationals do not form a group under addition or multiplication, but I want to find a binary operation $*$ such that $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}, *)$ is a group. It is possible by transpose of operation from $\mathbb{R}$, but I want a solid example.

Comment: What are the binary operations you are aware of, other than the two you've already mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Take a bijection $\varphi : (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \to \mathbb{R}$, and then define $a*b = \varphi^{-1}(\varphi(a) \cdot \varphi(b))$.

Comment: I want that bijection  φ ...I know it exists...so the desired group exists .But how to get the group

Comment: I think it's possible to specify such a bijection. We can get a bijection $f: \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R$ as follows: Let $S = \{n\sqrt 2: n\in \mathbb N\}$. Set $f(x) = x$ for $x\notin S$, and set $f(n\sqrt 2) = (n-1)\sqrt 2$ for $n\in \mathbb N$.

Now just enumerate the rationals and do the same trick for each one, taking care that the sets $S$ do not intersect.